# Oracle 11g user created with Create session but able to update the table?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I created a readonly user with only permission granted was create session and read only privilege, using the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502438/oracle-how-to-create-a-readonly-user

Now when I login with the new user I created I am able to update the table. 
Can anyone suggest me what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Please show us the **complete** script you used to create the user. And the update statement you are using.

Comment: Dear Colin, can you please check the link i have posted above. i use that sample code to create the user with only select privilege on the table

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502438/oracle-how-to-create-a-readonly-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a read only privilege. If someone grants update,delete,insert on x to public, everyone who can create a session can modify the contents of that table.

Also, if you create a user x and using a dba account create a table x.y, the user x - who owns the table y - can modify the contents of his/her table, because he/she is the owner of that table.

Comment: Dear Zelf, thanks for the response. I created the role with the select only privilege and i grated that role the the new user i have created. as instructed in the link below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502438/oracle-how-to-create-a-readonly-user

no the user didnt create the table and user have different table space other than the one where the database (table) he was able to modify (update) is located.

Comment: A user has privileges on a table, or not, independent from the tablespace where the table is located. Are privs on the table granted to the user 'PUBLIC'?

Comment: yes the privilege on the table granted to the user public. ok so is that whats causing the problem? thanks

Comment: yes, this seems to be your problem.